# How to cancel a previous javascript action

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make this where it will cut off an element if the character count is over X, then add a link to expand it back.

I have the working script here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3VM8A/)

The problem is, when the 'read-more' link is clicked, the previous `substr` just cuts it right back.

**How can I make this where it doesn't defeat itself?**

Comment: Please include your code sample directly in your question for those of us who don't have access to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3VM8A/1/) if you change:

```
$(object).text() = text;
```

to:

```
$(object).text(text);
```

Comment: Hah. See what happens when you skip the coffee. Thanks.